# matplotlib python finding graph intersection with x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have following code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 500)
Y = input("y = ")
y = eval(Y)

plt.axhline(0, color = "black") #x-axis
plt.axvline(0, color = "black") #y-axis
plt.grid() 
plt.plot(x, y)

x = 0
y0 = eval(Y) 
plt.plot(x, y0, marker="o", markersize=5, markerfacecolor="red", markeredgecolor="black")          
plt.annotate("[" + str(x) + ", " + str(y0) + "]", (x, y0))
plt.show()
```

I have found and annotated the intersection with y-axis. Now I would like to do the same with x-axis, but I can't find a way to do so. Can anybody help me?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Aside: `input = input("y = ")` and `y = eval(input)` are bad ideas. The first line overwrites `input` (you can't normally use that function anymore now). The second line evaluates everything the user inputs: `import os; os.remove('*')` would be evaluated and run as such. Yes, this is probably just a simple script for yourself, but bad habits can be hard to unlearn: don't use `eval`.

Comment: Instead of eval, just read a list of comma separated values or whatever, split on the comma, convert to floats and assign to y: `y = [float(value) for value in text.split(',')]`. Depending on the precise input (which apparently is 500 numbers).

Comment: Which part of your problem are you struggling with: finding the values of the intersection, or annotating it at that position? The first problem is mathematical in nature, the second problem relates to Matplotlib, but is essentially the same as your other annotation.

Comment: To find the intersection with the y-axis, y is obviously 0. Then solve for x in `0 = 2x + 1`, as that seems to be the equation from your graph.

Comment: Indeed I could do that for y = 2x+1. However my goal is to do that for any equation entered, not only 2x+1

Comment: If you're going to work with random equations of all sorts, perhaps [SymPy](https://pypi.org/project/sympy/) can be of use to you.

Comment: If you want to stick with NumPy, you have to do some (linear) interpolation to find an x-value for the y = 0 case.

Comment: SymPy looks quite interesting I'll have a look into it. Thank you

Comment: SymPy will probably also solve the `eval` issue for you in a safe way. Enjoy.